# Is it possible to read an "mbox" file passing the mbox data not a path?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mbox

All the mbox examples I've seen have code like this:

```
 final Store store = session
                        .getStore(new URLName("mstor:" + <path>);
```

Since I want to run the mbox code in a REST service, I need to be able to pass the mbox data itself in a variable instead of a disk path.

However, I cannot find any examples showing you can pass the data instead of a path and the API itself doesn't seem to have any methods supporting passing the data.

Has anyone successfully read mbox data using this mstor API to work without a path but instead using the mbox data?

If mbox API must get a disk path, perhaps a workaround for the REST service would be to create a temporary path using the mbox data "POSTed" and use that temporary path with the existing mbox API? Then, make sure the temporary file is gone when done.

Comment: A temp file is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yep, thanks! That's what I ended up doing. It works great. I just do a tempfile.delete() at the end of the POST method. Appreciate your reply. :)